# How to create a webhook between Bitbucket and Azure DevOps?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, bitbucket

We have all our repositories in Bitbucket and I'm trying to set up a continuous intergration services to Azure DevOps that would build the project after each push.

We have created a dedicated user account for Bitbucket repositories that has real-only access to all repositories.

However, creating a CI webhook trigger from Bitbucket to Azure Devops requires admin access to repositories. We do not want to give that level of access to CI user account.

I could add the webhook to Bitbucket repository manually, but I'm **missing the URL** to which the webhook should post the trigger.

The url is something like https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/_apis/public/hooks/externalEvents?publisherId ...

I think it's called **deployment trigger url** but I cannot find it anywhere. Does the new Azure DevOps support manually adding webhooks or do we have to do it manually somehow?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No I did not. I think there's no documentation on this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the same boat with you all. I don't want to give my CI account "Admin" rights to ANY repo.

My workaround so far has been to give the CI account temporary access in order to create the webhook when the pipeline is first saved, then downgrade it after the webhook has been created, knowing that any changes will require another temporary permission elevation.

FWIW, the webhook URL that is used is this: 
`https://[REDACTED].visualstudio.com/_apis/public/hooks/externalEvents?publisherId=bitbucket&channelId=[REDACTED]&api-version=5.1-preview`

As you can see, we are kind of in an understandable Catch-22 here, because we could conceivably create the pipeline and get that `channelId` to use to manually create the webhook in Bitbucket, but can't even SAVE a pipeline without repo Admin rights, so we can't get the `channelId`.

I wish there was a way to disable the webhook creation so we could manually create it on the Bitbucket side.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has been a long time since it was asked, but recently I was faced with the exact same issue and I thought I should add this here for anyone struggling to find out where these URLs are coming from.

I was seeing in Bitbucket two webhooks in the format [https://dev.azure.com/[myorganization]/_apis/public/hooks/externalEvents?publisherId=..](https://dev.azure.com/%5Bmyorganization%5D/_apis/public/hooks/externalEvents?publisherId=..). and I was trying to figure out how these were created in the first place.

As it turns out, when you create a new Bitbucket Pipeline in Azure and you select a repository for this pipeline, Azure automatically creates these webhooks for us in Bitbucket! In other words, it doesn't seem to be a way to deduce these URLs from anywhere, but rather they are created by Azure upon creation of the Pipeline, as well as they are deleted by Azure once you delete the Pipeline from Azure!.